# Objects Dont Match In Modes

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, objects, edit-mode

After I started to make seams to work on "TEXTURE" I decided to *Clear Seams* and restart

Now I get this in *Object Mode*. How did this happen? Also when I render I get the same image as *Object Mode*.

[image]

Comment: Was the object mode how it looked when you initially started sculpting?

Comment: No, It changed after I marked seams and unwrapped in UV, I am new to BLENDER (and the 3D world I might add) so I am assuming its something pretty easy for experienced artists

Comment: I still can't tell what happened but I'm pretty sure it has to do with your sculpt mode.

Comment: Haven't used SCULPT MODE yet but I will check it out. If you have any idea  what other thing might cause this partial render give me a holler

Comment: Can you post your blend?

Comment: Is there any modifier stick to your object?

Comment: To expand on @Carlo question, [modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) can be turned on/off for different modes, it looks like you may have a [remesh modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) that is disabled in edit mode.

Comment: Guys I just redid the project using just one object and extruding the heck out of it .. so far so good. Thanks.... (Ill send over the file tomorrow its 3am over here) :)